# Development for unstable versions of Chrome?

Tags: linux, macos, google-chrome, beta, google-chrome-os

I would like to know what the members of this great community think of developing and adjusting their web apps and sites in general to recent Google Chrome beta browsers on Linux and Mac OS X and of course Google ChromeOS.

Do you think it's too early and I shouldn't waste my time adjusting myself to something that might change due to bugs resolutions?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but Google Chrome rocks!

Comment: I'm a Firefox fan myself and our main development is done for Firefox and only then we adjust to all the other browsers on list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question.  While it is good to test against multiple browsers, there is very little point in testing against a beta browser - especially one with as little marketshare as Chrome.

With that said, the only reason I could see testing against a beta browser, is that you want your website to look good in it as soon as it is released and becomes mainstream.  But, I really only see this need arising for the browsers that, again, are more popular.

Answer (score 2):

Since Google Chrome uses [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) you could also (as an alternative) test against Safari or Konqueror instead. Chances are your test results will be very portable across these browsers.

Comment: I wish it was all that simple. Safari and Chrome are very similar due to the fact that they were both built upon Webkit, but the differences are way to big never the less.
There are even some weird differences between Safari 3.x and 4...

Answer (score 1):

Code against the standard, if you code it right the browsers will move toward you - rather than you constantly playing catchup.

Comment: For me Firefox is the most standard browser today, this is the reason why I force a strict policy to develop on Firefox first.
However, while I agree with your statement I simply can't afford for companies like Microsoft and Apple to fix their issues... I only have one life :)